# Google Analytics Reporting API: how can I filter by multiple cities?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I am working with the Google Analytics Reporting API. The problem I am running in to is that as far as I can tell the city dimension is not necessarily unique (i.e. multiple cities can have the same name.) So in order to filter to a specific city I need something like ga:country=France;ga:city=Paris which works fine, unless I want everything from Paris OR London. But the OR operator has a higher precedence than the AND operator in the filter expressions, and it doesn't look like there is a way to group expressions together.

So,

1. Are the strings returned by google analytics for ga:city uniquely identifiy a city?
2. Is there any way to group expressions together like (ga:country=France;ga:city=Paris),(ga:country=UK,ga:city=London)?
3. If neither of the above, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2):

One of the examples on the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) is:

> **Operating system is (Windows OR Macintosh) AND browser is (Firefox OR Chrome):**
>   ga:operatingSystem==Windows,ga:operatingSystem==Macintosh;ga:browser==Firefox,ga:browser==Chrome

In your situation you could do it in the way of (United Kingdom OR France) AND (Paris OR London) but it would still have your problem if there was a paris in the UK or a london in France.

A workaround would be to make one request where you query the cities in France, and a second different request where you query for the cities in the UK. It would mean making more requests but usually in these kind of cases having smaller but more specific requests is better practice. (And probably easier to manage)